# SED or AWK: change ${xxxx} to '{xxxx}'

Tags: awk, sed

There is variable ${world} in a file!

How do I change ${world} to '{world}'

Comment: Some example of your input and desired output would make your question clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
printf 'hello ${world}\n ${he} l ${lo} all\n' | sed "s/\${\([^}]*\)}/'\1'/g"
```

gives:

```
hello 'world'
 'he' l 'lo' all
```

From inside out:

- `[^}]*` means any non `}`character repeated 0 or more times
- `\(...\)` means remember whatever is in parentheses as `\1`
- `\$` means `$` character instead of end-of-line
- `g` means every occurrence of pattern in the line

Answer (score -1):

What do you actually want to catch? Literally xx? That would be easy:

```
echo '${xx}' | sed "s/\${xx}/\'{xx}\'/"
```

But I suspect that is not what you want